# Difference between 2 methods rewrite in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm migrating from Apache to nginx and need to convert massive httaccess file to nginx format.

1. I found 2 ways that work, which one should I use?

   ```
   location = /test.html {  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?action=temp&name=test; }
   ```

   or just

   ```
   rewrite ^/test.html$ /index.php?action=temp&name=test;
   ```
2. I'm putting this all in the file (ez_rewrite_list.conf) and then include in the virtual.conf. Where should I put that file location wise? Does it matter? am I doing right? any tips

   ```
   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  test.com;

       location / {
           root   /var/www/com/mysite;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
       }

       include /etc/nginx/ez_conf/ez_rewrite_list.conf;


       # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
       #
       location ~ \.php$ {
           root           /var/www/com/mysite;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
       }     
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgot to escape dot (`.`) in rewrite and they are not exactly the same.

Technically exact location should be a little faster than checking regexp for every request. Also you don't need to capture anything in rewrite inside the location, so I would use

```
location = /test.html {
    rewrite ^ /index.php?action=temp&name=test;
}
```

But actually, you'll never see any difference.